# How to refer to an internal docker registry?

Tags: docker

If I run

`docker run myown-couchbase`

and `myown-couchbase` is hosted on my own private docker registry.  How do I tell `docker-client` to refer to that registry? for example in maven i'm used to have a file `settings.xml` where I specify the `maven repositories` how do I specify that for `docker`?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For private docker registry, you need add the server and port when you refer the image. such as

```
docker pull my.registry.address:port/repositoryname
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry) for more infos.